# Are AWS services and EventBridge automatically integrated without the need for Roles or Resource based policies?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-event-bridge

The default event bus receives events from AWS services. Under normal circumstances, for one AWS service to talk to another AWS service, either Roles or Resource based policy comes into play. However, for publishing events to an event bus (which is part of AWS EventBridge, a separate service), an EC2 instance does not seem to need a policy added to a role attached to it (allowing it to publish instance state change events to event bus).

> Is the configuration for AWS services to publish events to AWS
> EventBridge handled automatically by AWS behind the hood without needing Roles or Resource based policies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> EC2 instance does not seem to need a policy added to a role attached to it

Your **EC2 instance does not publish** its state information to EB. It is done by EC2 service itself in the backend. Thus you do not need to add any instance role for that, because EC2 instance does not take  part in this process.

In contrast, if you want your application running on the EC2 to publish events onto EB bus, then **instance role will be required**.

I can't comment on all possible services in AWS if the behavior is same, but I would think that most operate in the same way as the EC2 service.

Comment: Thank you @Marcin - Understood. On a separate note, it gets a bit tricky to understand S3 bucket replication from a similar perspective because that seems to need a role (to do a bucket replication within its own service scope).

Comment: @AbhishekPalakkalKaliyath Yes, but the files are not transferred over EventBridge. AWS is inconsistent in regard of when a service role or other permissions are required. It varies from service to service. For some services you will need to explicitly create a role, for others a service role will be created for you, and other services will just use your IAM user's permissions to operate. Thus have to check docs for that. [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_aws-services-that-work-with-iam.html) is an overview of different ways AWS services work with IAM.

Comment: Correct, "AWS is inconsistent in regard of when a service role or other permissions are required. It varies from service to service" - this helps. Yeah, for replication, I was just taking an analogy; For EventBridge, AWS handles things automatically probably because that is a behavior they'd want to provide users by default without additional set up hassles.